# Cannot package electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium, electron-packager

I am unable to package my electron app using electron packager. I have installed electron packager by running the command **npm install electron-packager --save-dev**. I run **electron-pacakger .** command to package my application, but got this error again and again. Here is a screenshot of this:
[screenshot of error from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHtiL.png)

**Note**: I am using windows 10. My app runs on this OS by running command **npm start** just I cannot package it.

**Here is package.json file:**

```js
    {
"name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.1",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
  }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a script to call `electron-packager` – so I am confused about what you are trying to do. It doesn't just happen by itself – you need to tell it what to do. Here is the (edited) scripts section from a project I am working on. Assumes you have a directory named "release-builds" at the same level as the `package.json` file as specified by this line `--out=release-builds"`

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite  --platform=win32 --arch=x64   --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder -mw"
  },
```

And you would call it in the terminal through:

```
npm run package-mac
npm run package-win
```

Comment: I have added scripts tags that you have given and run the command npm run package-win but still, I have sam problem